# check availability of the username using ajax and jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here I am trying to check that username input is available for the user or not. I am doing it in codeigniter. 
Here is my view page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .no{color:red;}
        .yes{color:green;}
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                // unique user name checking ------------- starts here----------------
                $("#username").blur(function(){
                        var form_data= {
                            action : 'check_username',
                            username : $(this).val
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url : "check_unique_username",
                                data : form_data,
                                success : function(result) {
                                    $("#message").html(result.message);
                                    alert(result);
                                }
                        });
                });
                // unique username checking -------------- ends here-----------------
        });  

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="RegistrationForm" id="RegistrationForm" method="POST" action="">
        <label for="username">User Name</label>
        <div>
            <input id="username" name="username" size="25" class="required" />
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="button1" name="button1" value="check availability" />
        <div id="message"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

here is my controller code :

```
<?php
class Registration extends MX_controller {
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('registrationPage');  // this will load the registration page.
    }
    function unique_username() {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        if($action=='check_username'){
            $u = $this->input->post('username');
            $users=array("jhon","neo","margo","hacker","user123");
            if(in_array($u,$user)) {
                echo json_encode(array('message' => "It is not available!"));

            }
            else {
                echo json_encode(array('message' => "It is available!"));

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But my code is not working, where I am getting wrong,please help me out..showing only it is available for every username

**Edited :** I have changed my controller code...

Comment: 'my code is not working' - How?  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: @forsvarir `code not working` means its not showing whether username is available or not.

Comment: Your code is not working :) which part of your code not working ? what server returns ? Where is your firebug ?

Comment: I can see that you're using hmvc, posting your folder structure will help. I think the url: "check_unique_username" should be a php file.

Comment: did you check if the url : "check_unique_username" is actually giving a response? If you're using chrome press ctrl + shift + i then select console and comment in here what you see

Answer (score 1):

You have not used `#` while using the id of the div, so use:

```
$("#message").html(result);
```

instead of `$("message").html(result);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for help me in formatting.I will spend more time to format the answer.

Comment: @avinashse :- Please add alert(result) in success function and check what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: An updated answer to an updated question.

It's actually pretty stupid none of us could see it, but the problem is this string: `username : $(this).val`. The reason is that .val is not jQuery's method that get's the value of a text field, it should be `username : $(this).val()` (with brackets).

This covers the first JS part, the next problem is a typo, you have `url : "check_unique_username",`, but it should be `url : "registration/unique_username",` (didn't have controller name, and had unnecessary `check_` prefix while in controller the method was without it).

Next typo is in PHP - `if(in_array($u,$user)) {`, but we have an array `$users`, so change this to `if(in_array($u,$users)) {`, so PHP would not throw a notice.

Next problem is the missing line `dataType: 'json',` in AJAX request. We must put it so that JS could know what data type we are receiving and parse it in a correct way.

After that it should work. But I have some suggestion for you. Change the PHP, so that it would return not strings, but a boolean value. For example - true, if it's available, false if it's not.

```
if(in_array($u,$users)) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => false));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => true));
}
```

That way it would be easier to manipulate this data in your JS code. For example you could add this code to the success part of your AJAX request:

```
success : function(result) {
    if(result.message) { 
        $("#message").html("It's available!");
        $("#button1").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $("#message").html("It's not available!");
        $("#button1").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
```

And you will have your submit button enabled/disabled. This will make sure a normal user would not be able to submit the form if he entered a username that is taken.

Also I would change the event `blur` to `keyup`, that way you will have faster updates, but it's a bit more heavy on the server. Problem with `blur` event is that your user could fill the username and click on the button anyway, because blur event fires only after the user leaves the element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply @Vlakarados but why my code is not working.

Comment: I did that but that way is also not working, there is no checking of user availability :(

Comment: Use chrome or Firefox with firebug to see what the AJAX response is - in chrome precc Ctrl+Shift+C, open Network, make your page do the AJAX request, you will see it show up in the list, open it and view the preview tab. What data do you receive?

Comment: In firebug its showing :- POST http://module.com/index.php/user_registration/registration/unique_username 200 OK   44ms

In console,action I am getting `getting this page.{"message":"It is available!"}`

Comment: try in the `success` part: `alert(result.message)`. Also, I noticed a typo in my answer, it should be `$("#message").html(result.message);`, try both of these to see if anything shows up

Comment: in post its showing `action=check_username&username=undefined` i.e., they are not getting username submitted in the form

Comment: change `$u=$_POST['username'];` to `$u = $this->input->post('username');`, if you use codeigniter, you should use this over standard PHP. Try echoing this value then, see what you have there.

Comment: i have already change it to `$this->input->post('username');` but again showing same thing :(

Comment: Well, you should start with something less complicated then, try doing the same thing but without the database part. or maybe someone else will be able to answer what is your problem

Comment: I have changed my controller code, its not working , please have a look .. :(

Comment: I have completely change my answer, please see if it helps!